# How can i pass multiple thing in one props from child to parent?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have a child component and i want to make multiple things from one prop,
The main idea is i child component i have item this one i want to passed to parent and at the same time i want to close modal "change state from parent".

[image: shot]

So how can i handle it?

```
Const Child =(props) => {
        const [itemSelected,setItemSelected] = useState(null);
    
    const passData= ()=>{
        ....
        // I want here to send item selected and call a function from parent 
       // props.onPress( itemSelected, and let parent to call a function )
     }

   return (
      <Button onPress={passData} />
}


Const Parent = ()=>{
     Const sendData = ()=>{
         // Change parent state "close modal"
         // get data from child and send it to Api 
      }

     return (
       <Child onPress={sendData} />
     );
}
```

Comment: In parent - update ```sendData``` to accept a parameter ```itemSelected```.
In child - call ```props.onPress(itemSelected)``` from ```passData```.

Comment: @himayan Thanks its works, Can you just explain it more? why should I pass `itemSelected` through `props. onPress()`

Comment: Sure. I have posted a more detailed answer. I hope it helps. @Oliver D.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ideal way to pass data from `Child` to `Parent` in **React** is via functions passed as `props`.
I think, one of the main reasons why this got you confused is because of the naming of the function you have used.
For ease of understanding, I have renamed the `prop` passed as `onPress` to `sendData`. Let's see if it makes things easier. So, here are your components -

**CHILD**

```
Const Child =(props) => {
   const [itemSelected,setItemSelected] = useState(null);
   const passData = () => {
        ....
        props.sendData(itemSelected);
        // calling the function (sendData) received from Parent as a prop
        // with the data (itemSelected) from Child
   }

   return (
      <Button onPress={passData} />
   )
}
```

**PARENT**

```
const Parent = () => {
     const sendData = (itemSelected) => {
        // itemSelected is the data which you are receiving from Child
        // this function will be called from Child with the data passed as parameter
     }

     return (
        <Child sendData={sendData} />
        // sending the function to child
     )
}
```

Comment: hey @himayan again :3, 
I just have an update :D
now as you say in a child I can pass any props inside argument function, so in parent I can receive it as you write here `sendData = (itemSelected) => { ..}`
Now,
How can I use this itemSelected in other functions?
When I want to set this item to state I got this warning 
`cannot update a component from inside the function body of a different component`

Answer (score 0):

When you want to update the parent from child you can do something like this:

```js
const Child = ({update}) => {
    
    update("foo", "bar");
    
    return (
        <Text> Test </Text>
    )  
}
const Parent = () => {
     const [foo, setFoo] = useState('');
     const [bar, setBar] = useState('');

     const update = (f, b) => {
        setFoo(f);
        setBar(b);
     }
 
     return (
       <>
         <Child update/>
       </>
     }

}
```